# Alamofire with Objectmapper Issue

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, objectmapper

**UserInterest class:**

```
class UserInterest: Mappable {

var id: String?
var userId: String?
var interestId: String?

init() {

}

required init?(map: Map) {

}

// Mappable
func mapping(map: Map) {
    id               <-  map["ID"]
    userId           <-  map["UserId"]
    interestId       <-  map["InterestId"]
}

}
```

**UserInterestAPI class:**

```
class UserInterestAPI: Mappable {

var userInterestList: [UserInterest]?

init() {

}

required init?(map: Map) {

}

// Mappable
func mapping(map: Map) {
    userInterestList     <-  map["UserInterestList"]
}

}
```

I am using`Alamofire` for network call and`ObjectMapper` for JSON parsing. When I parse the UserInterestAPI then it parses as below.

```
["UserInterestList": 
    [
        ["ID": "1242fecd-9be6-49c5-96ed-0176dbe432b3", "InterestId": "998e1bec-e597-4c1f-9411-892eac780673", "UserId": "105536f2-ace8-43d4-8b53-32c245bea22d"], 
        ["ID": "fbff0439-83ee-4155-8987-7f3589bf76da", "InterestId": "c43d5161-89b8-41d1-be7f-b3ecb60d2347", "UserId": "105536f2-ace8-43d4-8b53-32c245bea22d"]
    ]
]
```

**Expected Request:** (Which is working in postman or fiddler)

```
{"UserInterestList": 
    [
        {"ID": "1242fecd-9be6-49c5-96ed-0176dbe432b3", "InterestId": "998e1bec-e597-4c1f-9411-892eac780673", "UserId": "105536f2-ace8-43d4-8b53-32c245bea22d"}, 
        {"ID": "fbff0439-83ee-4155-8987-7f3589bf76da", "InterestId": "c43d5161-89b8-41d1-be7f-b3ecb60d2347", "UserId": "105536f2-ace8-43d4-8b53-32c245bea22d"}
    ]
}
```

So in my API method I am not getting the list with size 2 and instead I  am getting list size as 0. I think this is because of the **[** instead of **{** for items in the parsed JSON. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: it seems like your UserInterestList is an array

Comment: @Umair Yes it is an array in my swift program as you can see above.

Comment: @Vinodh I searched a lot in web but no where I can find a solution for this. I am hoping it helps others too if we have a solution here.

Comment: What is your actual JSON response which you want to map ? can you share that ?

Comment: @Umair I have edited my question with the expected request. Also this is about request and not about response.